# error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment (swrots)

Tags: c

As I was trying to restore an old Star Wars mud I ran into this bug and unfortunately I am stuck.

This is the error I recieve when I try to compile "act_move.c"

```
act_move.c:591:27: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
 ( EXIT_DATA * ) pexit = xit;
```

Here is where the bug is located

```
ROOM_INDEX_DATA *generate_exit( ROOM_INDEX_DATA *in_room, EXIT_DATA * *pexit 
)
{
EXIT_DATA *xit, *bxit;
EXIT_DATA *orig_exit = (EXIT_DATA *) *pexit;

ROOM_INDEX_DATA *room, *backroom;

int brvnum;
int serial;
int roomnum;
int distance = -1;
int vdir = orig_exit->vdir;

sh_int hash;

bool found = FALSE;

if ( in_room->vnum > 32767 )    /* room is virtual */
{
  serial = in_room->vnum;
  roomnum = in_room->tele_vnum;

if ( (serial & 65535) == orig_exit->vnum )
{
  brvnum = serial >> 16;
  --roomnum;
  distance = roomnum;
}

else
{
  brvnum = serial & 65535;
  ++roomnum;
  distance = orig_exit->distance - 1;
}
backroom = get_room_index( brvnum );
}
else
{

int r1 = in_room->vnum;
int r2 = orig_exit->vnum;

brvnum = r1;
backroom = in_room;
serial = (UMAX( r1, r2 ) << 16) | UMIN( r1, r2 );
distance = orig_exit->distance - 1;
roomnum = r1 < r2 ? 1 : distance;
}
hash = serial % 64;

for ( room = vroom_hash[hash]; room; room = room->next )
if ( room->vnum == serial && room->tele_vnum == roomnum )
{
    found = TRUE;
    break;
}
if ( !found )
{
CREATE( room, ROOM_INDEX_DATA, 1 );
room->area    = in_room->area;
room->vnum    = serial;
room->tele_vnum   = roomnum;
room->sector_type = in_room->sector_type;
room->room_flags  = in_room->room_flags;
decorate_room( room );
room->next    = vroom_hash[hash];
vroom_hash[hash]  = room;
++top_vroom;
}
if ( !found || ( xit=get_exit(room, vdir)) == NULL )
{
xit = make_exit( room, orig_exit->to_room, vdir );
xit->keyword        = STRALLOC( "" );
xit->description    = STRALLOC( "" );
xit->key        = -1;
xit->distance = distance;
}
if ( !found )
{
bxit = make_exit(room, backroom, rev_dir[vdir]);
bxit->keyword       = STRALLOC( "" );
bxit->description   = STRALLOC( "" );
bxit->key       = -1;
if ( (serial & 65535) != orig_exit->vnum )
  bxit->distance = roomnum;
else
{
  EXIT_DATA *tmp = get_exit( backroom, vdir );
  int fulldist = tmp->distance;

  bxit->distance = fulldist - distance;
}
}
( EXIT_DATA * ) pexit = xit;
return room;
}
```

I must be looking way to hard at this. Any help would be appreciated and I apologize if this has been repeated anywhere else. I did search first.

Comment: You can't assign to a result of a cast in C, but I think there is/was a GCC extension for that. Try `-fpermissive` or an older version of GCC. If you're willing to change the code, you can just remove the cast and (in this case) it should just work.

Comment: Why not use `*pexit = xit;` as you have `EXIT_DATA * *pexit` and `EXIT_DATA *xit`. No cast is necessary.

Comment: `act_move.c:591:28: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
     ( EXIT_DATA * ) *pexit = xit;`

Comment: @CodeLyfe Weather Vane meant for you to get rid of the cast altogether.  Remove `( EXIT_DATA * )`

Comment: Worked Perfect. Thank you all very much.

Comment: Because I dont believe in free work. Ill reward you with the SRC code [link]https://github.com/codelyfe/SWROTS-MUD-RESTORED-2019 you helped restore. Even credited everyones help at bottom by posting link to this post on README.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [C Standard, § 6.5.4, footnote 104](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note104):

> **A cast does not yield an lvalue**. Thus, a cast to a qualified type has the same effect as a cast to the unqualified version of the type.

Emphasis mine.

You may not have a type-casted value as the destination for an assignment, since it's not an l-value. It would appear that since `pexit` is of type `EXIT_DATA **` and `xit` is of type `EXIT_DATA *`, this will work:

```
*pexit = xit;
```